# Hide UISearchbar as header inside UITableview when cancel is touched

Tags: uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have integrated a UISearchDisplayController into my controller's xib. The basic functionality I'm going for is to have the search bar in the header of the table, and a button in the navigation bar that shows the search display.

What I'm stuck on: When the cancel is touched, I want to make the searchbar invisible (keep the table so index 0 is show at top, not the search bar), but it stays visible and i'm not sure why (see 3rd image). Any ideas how to always keep the searchbar hidden when the cancel button is touched (see image 1).

What I've tried:

1. Setting the tableview contentOffset to 44. Which works initially.
2. Calling [tableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:....], which doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppeared:(BOOL)animated
{
        [self hidesSeachBar];
        [super viewWillAppeared:animated];
}

- (void)hidesSearchBar
{
        CGSize searchSize = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.bounds.size;
        //not complete
        [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, searchSize.height)];
}

- (void) searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    //Your code

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self hidesSearchBar];
}
```

Comment: This worked well for me. My only suggestion would be to name the method to "hideSearchBar" (instead of "hidesSearchBar") for the sake of clarity, since it is a command, and not querying a boolean value.

Answer (score 2):

If you've declared your search bar as a property like that

`@property(nonatomic, retain)UISearchBar *searchBar;`

you can set

`tableView.tableheader = nil;`

and set it back

`tableView.tableHeader = searchBar;`

when you'll need it again.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the content offset is the way to hide it, and you need to do that when the search is ended.  I'm using something like this:

```
- (void) searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController*)controller
{
    [self hideSearchBar];
}


- (void) hideSearchBar
{
    self.table.contentOffset = CGPointMake( 0, self.searchBar.frame.size.height );  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to hide the search bar of a UISearchDisplayController you have to set it to inactive. This will reshow the navigation bar as well

In your case, you must ensure that you adopt the UISearchBarDelegate protocol and then:

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: This just makes search bar inactive, that is, the same as you press its cancel button. And the question was how to hide it in case its in tableview header.

Answer (score 0):

To hide search bar on cancel, you need to call `UISearchBarDelegate` method:

```
(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    if(searchTask)[searchTask cancel];

    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];

   //reload you table here
}
```

Thanks