# Hide UISearchBar in a UITableView with a few rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Known solutions for hiding the UISearchBar don't work when the table contains just a few rows. For example,

```
 [self.companiesAndContatsTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 44)];
```

will work only if the number of cells in the table exceed the number of rows that fit on the screen. I want to hide search bar in every situation - especially when the table contains just a few rows and the user doesn't need the search functionality.

I tried to  add something like:

```
self.companiesAndContatsTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-44, 0,0, 0);
```

but I'm not allowed to move the position of my alphabet index section on the right side.

[image]

Comment: [yourTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380727/hide-uisearchbar-as-header-inside-uitableview-when-cancel-is-touched

Comment: I only need to hide the search bar when user see the controller for the first time, like [self.companiesAndContatsTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 44)]  method does when there are a lot of cells.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079820/how-can-we-hide-the-tableheaderview-and-tablefooterview